# Unable to parse a string to date when date format is unknown in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core, c#-4.0

I want to know if a particular string is a valid date or not while the date format can be any possible one.
(NOTE- date format is unknown).

Currently I am using

DateTime.TryParse, but its not working with all the dates as it is not parsing this date string=> 5-27-58.

Cant use DateTime.ParseExact it requires a specific date formates.

what is the best approach to do this.

Comment: You can't reliably parse a string to a date if you don't know the format. If I ask you what date 08/01/2021 represents, you can't possibly tell me. You'd have to make a guess between August 1st, 2021, and January 8th, 2021.

Comment: What date is 5-27-58 meant to represent, anyway? May 27th 1958? May 27th 2058? May 27th 0058? A date in a different calendar system? IMO you should work out what date formats you want to support, and then you can iterate over all those formats for any particular string, using the first matching one.

Comment: Actually, I want to know what date 20310 is? 2nd Mar 1910? 2nd Mar 2010? 20 Mar? 3rd Feb? 203 days into 1910? 10 weeks into the year 203? 20310 days since the epoch? You ask "is some string possibly any valid datetime?" - sure; parse it however you like to fit the result you want

Comment: Really thanks for ur valuable response. Will definitely go by specifying date format now.

Comment: You can also iterate through the cultures using System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures); and use the CultureInfo as parameter for DateTime.TryParse.